# Python Demo Web Projects on a Tornado Server?

Tags: python, web-applications, tornado, python-2.7

Are there any Python demo projects available I can learn from. I am basically looking into learning the basics like linking and creating a navigation bar.

I am currently trying to get the blog demo in the demo folder of Tornado to run, I am experiencing problems with the SQL file and do not know yet how to open it.

Besides that I would like to ask if there are more Python Demo Web Projects, one can learn from, perhaps somebody wold like to share a basic template example?

Answer (score 0):

Besides Tornado's standard examples, I recommend to digg into [tornadogists](http://tornadogists.com/) and [other gist snippets](https://gist.github.com/search?q=tornado).

Comment: Not sure if it's just me... but tornadogists link seems really suspicious - it's asking me to update my google chrome.  Don't click the install button for just in case.

Comment: Thanks @Raccoon, the link to tornadogists was wrong and it was pointing to a scum website. Fixed now.