# Is There a Tornado Equivalent of SimpleHTTPServer?

Tags: python, webserver, tornado, embeddedwebserver

Looking through the [demos](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/tree/master/demos), [TornadoGists](http://tornadogists.org/) and [other gist snippets](https://gist.github.com/gists/search?q=tornado&page=1) (based on [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266893/python-demo-web-projects-on-a-tornado-server)), I haven't found any code equivalent to `SimpleHTTPServer` from the standard library in Python. I'm looking for a really small web server that can handle concurrent requests, with all the boilerplate that `SimpleHTTPServer` includes for serving up files from the launch directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: as of Tornado 3, use the built in [StaticFileHandler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#StaticFileHandler).

Tornado isn't really designed for serving static files. If this will see any load, you should use nginx, or something like that. And if it won't, it might be easier to use `SimpleHTTPServer`.

That said, it's trivial to write one:

```
import os.path
import mimetypes

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

class FileHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, path):
        if not path:
            path = 'index.html'

        if not os.path.exists(path):
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404)

        mime_type = mimetypes.guess_type(path)
        self.set_header("Content-Type", mime_type[0] or 'text/plain')

        outfile = open(path)
        for line in outfile:
            self.write(line)
        self.finish()

def main():
    tornado.options.enable_pretty_logging()
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/(.*)", FileHandler),
    ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is just to get you started; if you're going to use it, you should make sure that you can't walk up the filesystem and access any file. Also, the script currently serves itself, which is a bit strange.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm looking for handling multiple requests concurrently. `SimnpleHTTPServer` doesn't handle that, at least not out of the box. I'll try your example tonight, but I've since tried Nginx and it seems to meet my needs.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize `SimpleHTTPServer` isn't concurrent, but of course, that makes sense. If you've got Nginx setup, stick with it; It'll be faster and more robust.

Comment: Yeah, mostly I wanted something that was low profile and easy to setup. Not having worked with Nginx before, I didn't realize how small it was compared to Apache.

Comment: As a command line `python -c "from tornado import web, ioloop; app = web.Application([(r'/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './'})]); app.listen(8000); ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()"`. Unlike SimpleHTTPServer this doesn't generate lists for folder content automatically.  Works if you know what files are present though.